# Find closest latlng from current location from list of latlng, stored in Firebase

Tags: google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

Im making apps in my freetime, and i've got a conundrum.

I've stored different user submitted places(in the form of markers) in my firebase database, and i want other users to be able to see these places if they are within a certain zoom distance of their current location. My firebase database looks like this:

```
userPlaces
- userToken
    - lat
    - lng
```

All i've got to work with at the moment is the current users own currentplace latlng. Im having difficulties seeing how i should make it so that they can see other users markers which are stored in firebase.

In short terms, the current user needs to be able to pull the information from firebase and put the relevant markers on the map, pertaining to where the user is at the moment. I dont want the code pull too much data aswell, so if there is anyway i could target the ones i need, that would be better (perhaps categorize latlng's if that's possible). If there are 1000 entries, i don't want to check each and every one of them, just so i can pull the correct ones.

In advance, thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/geofire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use firebase queries `orderByChild()` method on either `lat` or `lng` field. You must have a range for example say if your current lat is 30.00 then give me the results for places which are in the range of 20.00 to 40.00.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userPlaces")
            .orderByChild("lat").startAt(20.00).endAt(40.00)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    /* Write your logic here*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    /* Write your logic here*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    /* Write your logic here*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    /* Write your logic here*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    /* Write your logic here*/
                }
            });
```

This will help you fetch only relevant data that you require. But don't forget to put `.indexOn` in your firebase database rules otherwise it will download all the data on the client side and then filter it. Read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Go through the [complex queries using firebase realtime database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html). This might help you in restructuring your database structure in more optimised way.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try this out :)